# Automatic reconnect in case of network failures

Tags: zeromq, netmq

I am testing .NET version of ZeroMQ to understand how to handle network failures. I put the server (pub socket) to one external machine and debugging the client (sub socket). If I stop my local Wi-Fi connection for seconds, then ZeroMQ automatically recovers and I even get remaining values. However, if I disable Wi-Fi for longer time like a minute, then it just gets stuck on a frame waiting. How can I configure this period when ZeroMQ is still able to recover? And how can I reconnect manually after, say, several minutes? How can I understand that the socket is locked and I need to kill/open again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to find an answer on their GitHub https://github.com/zeromq/netmq/issues/845. Seems that the behavior is by design as I got the same with native zmq lib via .NET binding.

Comment: If you have followed the native API details and activated all low-level configuration details of the zmq_socket_monitor()-instance, then the "missing" event-reports are the responsibility of the current .NET ZeroMQ binding. If you've left the monitor without setting up details, no surprise it does neither monitor, the less report, any events (once not having been configured to do so). Having read Somdorons remarks on ZMTP/2 vs ZMTP/3 made me sort of surprised, how it could've been possible to omit so many native-API features from the .NET binding ( mea culpa - ZMTP RFCs are "recommendations" )

Comment: I was playing with monitoring using NetMQ only, so yes, specifics of that version

Answer (score 1):

> **Q :**
> *<sub>" How can I **configure** this ... ?"</sub>*

**A :**
Use the .NET versions of `zmq_setsockopt()` detailed parameter settings - family of link-management parameters alike `ZMQ_RECONNECT_IVL`, `ZMQ_RCVTIMEO` and the likes.

All other questions depend on your code.

If using blocking-forms of the `.recv()`-methods, you can easily throw yourself into unsalvageable deadlocks, best never block your own code ( why one would ever deliberately lose one's own code domain-of-control ).

If in a need to indeed understand low-level internal link-management details, do not hesitate to use `zmq_socket_monitor()` instrumentation ( if not available in .NET binding, still may use another language to see details the monitor-instance reports about link-state and related events ).

Comment: Thanks, your answer helped me to google with the right keywords